# How to bind an image source in bin/debug?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel  MouseLeftButtonDown="Lamp_Click" Name="Lamp" Background="White" Width="34" Height="35">
            <Grid Height="30">
                <Image  Source="images/{Binding Path}">
                    
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="7" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="-1,19,1,-12"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
       
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C# code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static List<ViewModel> List{ get; set; } = GetAll();
    
    public static List<ViewModel> GetAll()
    {
       // get records from data base.

    }
}
```

This code has syntax error. How can I change images/{Binding path} to a valid. why this code has error? I'm really confused. Please help me.

Comment: Show the implementation of the ViewModel type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image  Source="images/{Binding Path}">
```

XAML doesn't support this kind of half binding thing you're doing, you either bind something or you don't. And even if it did, it wouldn't work like that because `Image.Source` isn't a `string`, it's an [`ImageSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=net-6.0).

Instead you need to create a converter that converts your `Path` binding (a string) to an `ImageSource` by instantiating a `BitmapImage` and setting its source to load the image asynchronously.

Comment: A regular string or Uri is enough.
The binding itself will call the required converter.

Comment: `StringFormat` isn't enough to perform the concatenation, if that's what you mean. The implicit converter doesn't use it before performing the conversion. You need a converter.

Comment: There is implicit conversion from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to `ImageSource`, provided by ImageSourceConverter - a TypeConverter class. You do not need a Binding Converter.

Comment: Feel free to try it without a converter, I did and it doesn't work. Or is the issue that you didn't read the question and that he wants to append a string to the binding?

Comment: The Binding isn't valid - as you correctly point out. It should be `Source="{Binding Path}"` where the `images/` prefix becomes part of a relative or absolute file path, or a resource file pack URI, or whatever, returned by the Path property. That Binding will work without a Converter. The "*wouldn't work*" part of your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: You may want to take a look at `[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter))]` on the [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=net-5.0) declaration - that provides the implicit conversion mentioned before.

Comment: Thats clever. I think there was no way.